# Access DynamoDB in Golang Fargate Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-fargate

I'm trying to access DynamoDB from my Fargate task, which is written in golang. And all I get is a timeout. What I am missing?

I'm using the Cloudformation templates from AWS Labs [(here)](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/ECS) plus a task role that allows full DynamoDB access. It's the simplest public subnet template plus the Fargate one.

I tried adding a VPC endpoint, but it made no difference.

Running the task on my machine works.
Running a Python (Flask) task that does (more or less) the same works both locally and on AWS. It's the same setup, I just changed the task image.

This is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/endpoints"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "time"
)

var db *dynamodb.Client

func init() {
    cfg, err := external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic("unable to load SDK config, " + err.Error())
    }
    cfg.Region = endpoints.UsEast2RegionID
    db = dynamodb.New(cfg)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("go!")
    router := gin.New()
    router.Use(gin.Recovery())
    router.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) { c.JSON(200, gin.H{"msg": "pong"}) })
    router.GET("/pong", func(c *gin.Context) {
        req := db.ListTablesRequest(&dynamodb.ListTablesInput{})
        ctx := context.Background()
        ctx, cancelFn := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*5)
        defer cancelFn()
        res, err := req.Send(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(400, gin.H{"msg": "Fail", "error": err.Error()})
            return
        }
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"msg": fmt.Sprint(res)})
        return
    })
    router.Run()
}
```

Timeout:

```
helles:v2> curl  xyz.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/pong
{"error":"RequestCanceled: request context canceled\ncaused by: context deadline exceeded","msg":"Fail"}
```

Expected:

```
helles:v2> curl 127.0.0.1:8080/pong
{"msg":"{\n  TableNames: [\"OneTable\",\"OtherTable\"]\n}"}
```

Python for comparison:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from flask import Flask
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.client("dynamodb")
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/ping")
def index():
    return "pong"

@app.route("/pong")
def pong():
    return dynamodb.list_tables()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

The result is a bit different, with metadata added, but the table names are there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Problem was with the Docker base image I was using. My Dockerfile was:

```
FROM scratch
ADD ./build/api/api /
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/api"]
```

With a statically linked executable.

Changing `FROM scratch` to `FROM gcr.io/distroless/base` made it work.

My guess is that the application/dynamodb client wasn't able to resolve the service address without the missing parts from the base image.

Thanks @Dude0001.

Comment: Solved the issue I had, which to way too much to resolve :|

Answer (score 0):

Timeout is often a network Issue. Have you checked security groups used by both the ECS task and Dynamo DB. Need to make sure you have rules setup to egress out of ECS and ingress into DynamoDB on the correct ports.

You said you setup an endpoint for Dynamo in the VPC. Not clear from your OP if you are trying to connect to private endpoint in a private VPC or if you are trying to go through the public internet. If you are trying to go through public internet you need to also check that your ECS task is in a VPC that has a NAT gateway out to the public internet. It looks like you are trying to connect through 127.0.0.1 or an ELB DNS to connect to the DynamoDB service which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Looks like networking indeed. Except the python task runs ok in the same setup. I just changed the task image. Before setting the task role I got an invalid credentials error, so I assumed the network was ok.
I'm trying the simplest setup that will work. Hence the use of the templates from AWS.
Thanks

The VPC endpoint was an experiment and made no difference.

Comment: What server address are you using to connect to DynamoDB?

Comment: I'm not using any explicit address. Just setting the region on the client. See `init()` function.

Comment: Are you trying to access a local DynamoDB or the AW DynamoDB service? Either way you need to tell your client what to connect to.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NET.01.html

Comment: I'm trying to access the AWS service.

Comment: Then you need to give the client the http address to your DynamoDB as in the link I shared

Comment: Hah. Problem was with the base image. The DynamoDB Go package doesn't need an address. There isn't an option to pass and it never shows in the docs or tutorials. The client must work with something from the host to resolve the service address and that part was missing from the bare bones image I was using. Thanks!

Comment: Okay not familiar with Dynamo Go and missed that part. You said you were trying to access the AWS Service and that through me off. Glad you figured it out.